# Filling a field triggers request and redirect

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, cucumber, capybara, poltergeist

I'm writing cucumber feature specs using capybara, with poltergeist as the Javascript driver.

In one scenario, a step asks capybara to fill in a number field:

```
When /^I set the group count to (\d+)$/ do |group_count|
  within 'form#new_practitioner_activity' do
    find('input#number_of_groups').set group_count
  end
end
```

For some reason, at that step a request gets generated (I've used Poltergeist's `page.driver.network_traffic` object to check it out) and the whole scenario is derailed as the request is redirected to the welcome page.

Changing the value of the field does trigger some Javascript (that's the point of writing the scenario to test it), but when I run in Chrome and watch the network panel, I don't see any requests there, and the JS code isn't intended to make any calls back to the server. (The script picks up a nested form, clones it, and appends it, if that matters.)

Here's the Coffeescript relevant to the field change. I'm eliding a good bit of each of these classes to try to clarify it.

```
class GroupCountElement
  constructor: (@controller, @form) ->
    # On instantiation we set up instance attributes for a div, and an input 
    # contained in it
    @input = @form.find('.input.group-count')
    @inputField = @input.find('input#number_of_groups')
    @form.on('change', 'input#number_of_groups', @countChanged)

  countChanged: =>
    @form.trigger('groupcount:changed')

  val: (newValue) =>
    # This method just lets us treat the object like an input element
    if newValue?
      @inputField.val(newValue)
    else
      @inputField.val()
```

Here's what `@form` does with that `groupcount:changed` event:

```
class Form
  constructor: (@controller, @form, @academicYearId) ->
    # ... other setup stuff...
    @groupInputs = []
    @form.find('.group-activity').each (i, row) =>
      @groupInputs.push(new GroupActivity(@controller, @form, row))
    @groupCount = new GroupCountElement(@controller, @form)

    @form.on('groupcount:changed', @groupCountChanged)

  groupCountChanged: (e) =>
    delta = @groupCount.val() - @groupInputs.length
    if delta > 0
      @groupInputs.push(new GroupActivity(@controller, @form)) for i in [1..Math.min(delta, 10-@groupInputs.length)]
    else if delta < 0
      @groupInputs.pop().delete() for i in [Math.max(delta, 1-@groupInputs.length)..-1] unless @groupInputs.length is 1
```

Then this is the GroupActivity class which is having instances of itself pushed and popped on the Form:

```
class GroupActivity
  constructor: (@controller, @form, @groupForm) ->
    if @groupForm?
      # This means we're creating an instance reflecting DOM already in the form
      @$groupForm = $(@groupForm)
    else
      # This means we're cloning an existing chunk of DOM - a row - and adding 
      # it to the form
      @$groupForm = @form.find('.group-activity').last().clone()
      # Because the nested form elements we just cloned have names
      # and IDs with an array index, our new row needs to have those
      # attributes updated with the index +1. @incrementFormAttrs()
      # handles that.
      @incrementFormAttrs()
      @append() # Sticks the cloned DOM into the form
      @reset()  # Clears any values in the cloned DOM

  incrementFormAttrs: =>
    oldIndex = @$groupForm.find('.input.instructional-focus label').attr('for').match(/practitioner_activity_group_activities_attributes_(\d+)/)[1]
    newIndex = parseInt(oldIndex, 10) + 1
    @$groupForm.find('label').attr 'for', (i, val) ->
      val.replace(/practitioner_activity_group_activities_attributes_(\d+)/, "practitioner_activity_group_activities_attributes_#{newIndex}")
    @$groupForm.find('select, input').attr
      id: (i, val) -> val.replace(/practitioner_activity_group_activities_attributes_(\d+)/, "practitioner_activity_group_activities_attributes_#{newIndex}")
      name: (i, val) -> val.replace(/practitioner_activity\[group_activities_attributes\]\[(\d+)\]/, "practitioner_activity[group_activities_attributes][#{newIndex}]")

  append: =>
    @$groupForm.insertBefore( @form.find('.actions') )

  reset: =>
    if @$groupForm
      new Deselector(@$groupForm.find('select'))
      @$groupForm.find('input').val(undefined)

  delete: =>
    @$groupForm.remove()
```

So, to trace it out: the test changes the value of the `@inputField` in the GroupCountElement. That sends a `groupcount:changed` event to the Form, which calls its `groupCountChanged()` method. In this case the number is most likely to go UP, so we're adding at least one GroupActivity instance, which in its constructor will call `incrementFormAttrs()`, `append()`, and `reset()`.

None of these should trigger a request as I understand them. What could be kicking off this extra request which is breaking my test?

Comment: Can you include that JavaScript code?

Comment: Edited to include the relevant Coffeescript. Thanks for reading it; the script is pretty dense.

Comment: Updating Poltergeist and Capybara *seems* to have made the problem go away, but the update raised other issues in our test suit, so I'm not quite sure. (Previously Capybara 1.1.3 and Poltergeist 1.0.2; updated to 2.4.4 and 1.5.1, respectively.)